# How to add links to android APP sidebar tray?

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

i have the following codes and i just want to add few links in sidebar tray.
The tray and all works good, simly add some links in the tray and all is good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- Main content -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Add this code before the home button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/drawer_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="#000"
            android:onClick="openDrawer"
            android:text="MORE"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:verticalScrollbarPosition="left"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/homes"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />


        <!-- Your existing home button -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/homes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#000"
            android:onClick="gohome2"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
            app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#000"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#000"
                android:padding="99dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/logomain_23" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <!-- Sidebar navigation drawer -->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:listitem="@layout/nav_list_item"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

any idea where to update the codes? i have been trying for long.
i want to add few links in the tray sidebar when the more button is clicked.

basically how to change the tray xml or UI ?